# How to save Doctrine2 Entity

Tags: php, orm, save, doctrine-orm

How to save Doctrine2 Entity if all fields are private? Is there some kind of mechanism to do that?

How can I save this:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class SomeEntity
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue */
    private $id;

    /** @Column */
    private $title;

}
```

How to change `title` for example? Maybe it's possible via EntityManager?

PS: Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10):

```
class SomeEntity
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue */
    private $id;

    /** @Column */
    private $title;

    public function setTitle($title){
        $this->title = $title;
    }
}
```

Use like this:

```
$entity = new SomeEntity();
$entity->setTitle('title');
$em->persist($entity); //$em is an instance of EntityManager
$em->flush();
```

This is a proper way emphasized in the [manual](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-objects.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
public function __get($property)
{
    return $this->$property;
}

public function __set($property,$value)
{
    $this->$property = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted you should define getters and setters. You can do this manually or on console:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Acme/StoreBundle/Entity/SomeEntity
```